# Pandas - select rows whose column value appears `n` times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to retrieve a random df entry from all the entries of a df that appear `n` times in the df itself, but am facing some problems.
This is the code I'm using, with `n` = 2.

```
d = {
    "letters": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a", "d", "d"], 
    "one": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    "two": [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
s = df["letters"].value_counts()
df2 = df.loc[np.where(s.to_numpy() == 2)]
rand = df2.sample(n=1, random_state = 2)
```

This would look ok to a first look, but inspecting df2 returns that df2["letters"] has two entries: "b" and "c', and clearly "c" does not appear twice in the original df.

I guess that the error needs to be in the way I define the concept of "look only to the entries that appear `n` times, but I can't wrap my mind around this.

What is going on here, and how can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by original column `letters` for filtering:

```
s = df["letters"].value_counts()
df2 = df[df["letters"].map(s) == 2]

print (df2)
  letters  one  two
1       b    1    2
4       b    1    2
6       d    1    2
7       d    1    2
```

Then if need random row per `letter`s use:

```
rand = df2.groupby('letters').sample(n=1, random_state = 2)
print (rand)
  letters  one  two
4       b    1    2
6       d    1    2
```

Comment: This is actually a great solution. Works too for the sampling step, as the probability of picking any entry is not affected by the doubling of the entries. How would one avoid it though?

Comment: @AntonioCarnevali - Do you need random values per `letter`s? Added to answer.